# Testng dealing with test inheritance

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have **(Test-A)** fully annotated testng test in one project. Note: this test runs successfully. Then I have another testng test **(Test-B)** in a different project extending **(Test-A)**. This new **(Test-B)** does not have any annotations since its extending a class that does. My expectation is that when you run this test **(Test-B)**, it should run the test-cases in the super class in addition to the testcase defineed within it which is the object-oriented way. The problem is that testng does not even recognize it as test since there is no annotation within it. I guess testng annotation processing does not consider super-class's annotation??

Comment: I just noticed that all that is required to run all the tests in the superclass is to add one single annotated test in the child class that calls one testcase in the superclass. This causes all the testcase in the super class to run. weird?

Comment: another update. Any test in the child class is enough to trigger all tests in super class to run. It doesnt have to be a test that calls the super class test.

Comment: you should submit the answer to your own question. Otherwise it is "unanswered" and wastes time of those who want to answer unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note, using plain old JUnit 4 here, not TestNG)

Eclipse does appear to look up the class hierarchy for @Test annotations if the parent class is in the same project.  The following example worked for me:

```
public class A {
    @Test public void a() {

    }
}

public class B extends A {

}
```

When running `B` as a JUnit Test, it executes `a()` and passes.

I then created two Eclipse projects, Test A and Test B.  I made project B link to project A and repeated the above steps like you did, with class A in project A etc.  Now, running class B as a unit test says 'No JUnit tests found.'  Then, adding a `@Test` to class B solves the problem.

So, we can deduce that Eclipse doesn't leave the bounds of the current project when looking for test cases.  I think your workaround of adding a single `@Test` to your class is a reasonable one, although I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the test running environment and setup in question (which may require more digging), but I was able to solve this for my case (same problem using such an inheritance pattern for TestNG 7) by adding a `@Test` annotation on the sub-class itself:

```
public abstract class A {

    @Test
    public void aTest() {

    }
}

@Test
public class B extends A {

}
```